# foreach repeats in the performance profiler C#

Tags: c#, .net, profiler

I am profiling C# application and encountered the following scenario. I would appreciate, if anyone could explain the behavior.

I have the following original C# code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        people.Add(new Person{firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith"});
        people.Add(new Person{firstName = "Jim", lastName = "Johnson"});
        people.Add(new Person{firstName = "Sue", lastName = "Rabon"});

        foreach (Person p in people)
            Console.WriteLine(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
    }
}
```

C# performance profilers are showing the above code as follows :

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        people.Add(new Person{firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith"});
        people.Add(new Person{firstName = "Jim", lastName = "Johnson"});
        people.Add(new Person{firstName = "Sue", lastName = "Rabon"});

        foreach (Person p in people)
        foreach (Person p in people)
        foreach (Person p in people)
        foreach (Person p in people)
        foreach (Person p in people)
            Console.WriteLine(p.firstName + " " + p.lastName);
    }
}
```

The foreach loop is repeated. Why is this happening? If I use code de-compiler, then it is similar to original source code.

Comment: The profiler is apparently wrong.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `Console.WriteLine` call in curly braces? I know it _shouldn't_ make a difference, but might be worth an experiment. On a side note I'd be sad if I found this code - why call a List "peopleArray"? :-(

Comment: Are you using the built in profiler with VS? What version of VS are you using? Which performance test did you run? Where are you seeing this result? Those questions aside, it's most likely just a bug since the decompiled code is almost the same as the original, plus it would make absolutely no sense for the compiler to do that. I am using VS 2010 and used your code with the built in profiler; I did not get the same bug as you.

Comment: VS 2012, .Net Framework 4.0 and dotTrace Performace 5.3

Comment: I like `peoples` a lot better than `peopleArray` :)

Comment: I tried running in VS2012 profiler and got the following error : Injection of runtime library failed. May I request some one to try this code in ANTS profiler?